# Create typed definations(.d.ts) from jsDoc using javascript nested functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, tsc

```
/**
 * Returns a string object with various string manipulation functions.
 * @param {string} string - The input string.
 * @returns {StringFunctions}
 */

export function string(string) {

    let fn = () => {};
    /**
     * @memberof StringFunctions.prototype
     * @returns {boolean} True if the string is a string, false otherwise.
     * @inner
     */
    fn.prototype.isString = function () {
        return typeof string === 'string'
    }

    fn.prototype.capitalize = function () {
        return (string.toLowerCase()).replace(/(?:^|\s|["'([{])+\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
    }
    fn.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
        return string.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function (word, index) {
            return index === 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
        }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
    }
    fn.prototype.toSnakeCase = function () {
        return string && string.match(
                /[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
            .map(s => s.toLowerCase())
            .join('_');
    }
    fn.prototype.toKebabCase = function () {
        return string
            .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2")
            .replace(/[\s_]+/g, '-')
            .toLowerCase();
    }
    fn.prototype.toPascalCase = function () {
        return (' ' + string).toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)/g, (m, chr) => {
            return chr.toUpperCase()
        });
    }
    fn.prototype.toLowerCase = function () {
        return string.toLowerCase()
    }
    fn.prototype.toUpperCase = function () {
        return string.toUpperCase()
    }

    fn.prototype.firstNChars = function (n = 10) {
        return string.slice(0, n);
    }

    fn.prototype.lastNChars = function (n = 10) {
        return string.slice(-n);
    }


    return new fn();
}`
```

I get below defination as below(.d.ts)
I want to get typed infromation about all child or nested functions

```
/**
 * Returns a string object with various string manipulation functions.
 * @param {string} string - The input string.
 * @returns {StringFunctions}
 */
export function string(string: string): StringFunctions;
```